# Refining a Sublime Text 2 / Transmit workflow

Tags: text-editor, ftp, sublimetext

I recently changed code editors from Coda to Sublime Text 2. All in all, I am finding that ST2 fits my web development workflow almost perfectly.

My one friction point is when interacting with an FTP server. I use Transmit (from Panic) to mount the server as a mounted disk. I then open that disk as a project in ST2.

When I do that, the Command-T / Command-P shortcuts in ST2 (used to quickly open any file using fuzzy matching) and the Find In Files feature does not return results until I drill down to those directories in the sidebar.

Now, I believe this is because Transmit has yet to "open" those directories and so the file system is unaware of what is in each directory.

Is there a way to either force Transmit to "open" those directories so they load instantly in ST2, or another alternative I haven't discovered yet?

Comment: Are you using the latest Transmit 4 and ST2? I just downloaded the Transmit trial to test this and it seemed to work great fuzzy matching as well as find in files starting at root. No folders had been click on. I just dragged the newly mounted drive to the ST2 icon to start my project.

Comment: Interesting. I'm running Transmit 4.2 with Sublime Text 2 (Build 2220) and finding drilling through directories with even the sidebar has a very noticeable delay before I can see the files.

Are you using the Transmit Menu via the Menubar? Or in the app itself?

I'll try it tomorrow with a site I have with a different host — maybe one server is just naturally slower?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

A follower on Twitter recommended [Sublime FTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) ($16), a third-party add-on by the author of Package Control, Will Bond.

For my own setup, I use his [Sublime SFTP Solution](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/sidebar#SublimeSFTP) which maps a local folder to the remote version. This setup allows me to quickly access my files.

Since working with remote files can come with some risk, I use Joel Thornton's [Automatic Backups](https://github.com/joelpt/sublimetext-automatic-backups) add-on to create a time-stamped backup of whatever file I have just saved. That way, in case something tragic happens, I can quickly roll back to an earlier version of my file.